# Search/match algorithm between 2 vectors

Tags: algorithm, objective-c, matrix, facebook

I have 2 vectors of Facebook-like pages which are represented by an ID from 2 different users. I want to verify the number of liked pages that are similar between these 2 users.

This is my algorithm that I am using right now, which is basically a search into all rows and columns of a matrix:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 val = [user_like objectAtIndex:i];
 id like_user = [[val allValues] objectAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"like user %d is %@",i, like_user);

 for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {

 val2 = [friend_like objectAtIndex:j];
 id like_friend = [[val2 allValues] objectAtIndex:2];
 NSLog(@"like friend %d is %@",j, like_friend);

 if (like_user == like_friend) {
 //do something
 }

 }

 }
```

How can I optimize this search/match algorithm?

Comment: Here at Code Review, we like to review **the full code**. Looking at your code, you write `//do something`, which shows that you did not post the full code, therefore making it off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some problems with this code I want to address before I even get into optimization of speed.

First of all, there's absolutely no indentation, which makes this very hard to read.

Second of all, your variable names are both lacking, and not in keeping with Objective-C standard conventions.  Variable names like `val` and `val2` aren't really descriptive enough.  A variable name like `like_user` may be descriptive enough (I don't know, it's borderline), but Objective-C standards suggest that the variable should instead be named `likeUser`.  We prefer camel casing to underscoring.

Next, you're using a `for` loop where you should be using a `forin` (I'll get to that later), but we're using the loop iterator as an index into an array... which is fine-ish... but you're concerning yourself with the array's length in the `for`'s condition.  You're risking an index out of bounds exception.

But we really don't want to use a `for` loop anyway.  Any time we need to do something with each object in an Objective-C collection, we should use a `forin` loop anytime we can.  `forin` loops run faster than regular `for` loops--they're processed in batches.

But as 200_success points out, in this specific instance, we don't need to iterate through the indexes.

You stated you just want to count the number of common liked pages.

So, just as 200_success suggested:

```
NSSet *userLikeSet = [NSSet setWithArray:userLike];
NSMutableSet *commonLikeSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:friendLike];
NSSet *commonLikes = [commonLikeSet intersectSet:userLikeSet];

NSInteger commonLikeCount = [commonLikes count];
```

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), which is inefficient.  Use an [`NSMutableSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html) to compute the intersection of two sets.

```
NSSet *userLikeSet = [NSSet setWithArray:user_like];
NSMutableSet *commonLikeSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:friend_like];
[commonLikeSet intersectSet:userLikeSet];
```

Comment: This answer is fine if the order of the objects is not important.

Comment: After rereading the question though, he actually just needs a count, so this is a good option.